# Access to File being restricted after Ubuntu crashed

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, gnome

My Ubuntu 8.10 crashed due to the overheating problem of the CPU when I am opening some directory and intend to do some file transfer under Nautilus. After reboot, under gnome, all the files cannot be removed, their properties cannot be  viewed and they can only be opened, although all are still fine under terminal. I was wondering why is that and how can I fix it?

Thanks and regards

---

UPdate

```
$ cat /etc/mtab  
/dev/sda7 / ext3 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0  
tmpfs /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0  
/proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0  
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0  
varrun /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0  
varlock /var/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777 0 0  
udev /dev tmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0  
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0  
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620 0 0  
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0  
lrm /lib/modules/2.6.27-15-generic/volatile tmpfs rw,mode=755 0 0  
/dev/sda8 /home ext3 rw,relatime 0 0  
/dev/sda2 /windows-c vfat rw,utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0 0  
/dev/sda5 /windows-d fuseblk rw,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0  
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0  
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0  
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/tim/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=tim 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Open up the terminal.

Type:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Now try to do whatever your trying to do in nautilus.

Note that this will open up nautilus as the root user. The desktop and home folders will link to the root users profile so you'll have to navigate over to your own profile under File System and then home.

you can also type `chmod 777 filename` in the terminal in order to set full read write and execute permissions for all users.

EDIT:

Please do an ls -al on the files you are talking about and paste them in so we can see the permissions and ownership of the files. If you are listed as the owner and group of those files and the permissions are set to full access... you might want to try running fsck -fy /dev/hda1 (or sda1) from single user mode or from a live cd

Comment: Thanks! The permissions are all fine, and I think no need to set them. Yes, opening nautilus in root works, but how can I make it work for my own account?

Comment: Afer a while when I switched to root to use nautilus, I just found that my account can operate on the files again. Not sure what made the change. Maybe it took a while for nautilus to recover from last Ubuntu crash, or running nautilus under root make it happen?

Comment: Is it more likely the problem of nautilus or of the filesystem?

Comment: It is more likely an issue with the filesystem especially since you say this happened after a crash. Doing a forced power-off while Ubuntu is reading or writing can cause something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that problems displaying files in Nautilus are tied to your user from your error description. Does the same problem occur if you log in as another user? Have you tried to rename `$HOME/.gnome` and `$HOME/.gnome2` to something else?

Comment: Thanks! What do $HOME/.gnome and $HOME/.gnome2 do respectively? Will renaming them cause any trouble?

Comment: Those directories contains various gnome application settings, so renaming them is sort of a configuration reset. Applications should be able to work without them.